# Detect scroll end in MAUI ScrollView on Mac Catalyst platform

Tags: maui

I am using MAUI ScrollView and I want to listen to the completion of the ongoing scrolling operation (ScrollEnded). Unfortunately, there is no build-in event available. So, I looked for native support by accessing its handler. I tried the following events. But nothing is invoked when the scrolling is about to end.

[image]

Please let me know if anyone know how to detect the scroll end event either accessing the native code or maui code.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake and there is no api in the native Catalyst or the maui can detect if the scrollview scrolled completely. You can post a feature request on the github.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to detect the end of a scrollview you can calculate the end item with the `OnScrolled` event. This is how it can be done.

```xml
<ScrollView x:Name="myScrollView" Scrolled="OnScrolled">
    <StackLayout x:Name="myStackLayout">
        <!--  Items  -->
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And the Event:

```cs
private void OnScrolled(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewHeight = myScrollView.Height;
    var contentHeight = myScrollView.ContentSize.Height;
    var currentScrollPosition = myScrollView.ScrollY;

    if (currentScrollPosition + scrollViewHeight >= contentHeight)
    {
        Toast.Make("I am at the bottom").Show();
    }
}
```